# Math incomprehension $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial\dot{q}^{\lambda}}=g_{\lambda\mu}\dot{q^{\mu}}+g_{o \lambda}$

Tags: partial-derivative, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Mathematically speaking I do not understand why from

\begin{equation}
T(q^{\lambda},\dot{q}^{\lambda},t)= \dfrac{1}{2} \,g_{\mu \nu} \, \dot{q}^{\mu} \, \dot{q}^{\nu} + g_{0 \mu} \, \dot{q}^{\mu}+g_{0 0}
\end{equation}
I get that: $$\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial\dot{q}^{\lambda}}=g_{\lambda\mu}\dot{q^{\mu}}+g_{o \lambda}$$
where:  $\,\, g_{\mu \nu } (q^{\lambda},t)  \,\,\,\,
g_{\mu 0} (q^{\lambda},t) \,\,\,\,
g_{0 0} (q^{\lambda},t) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the indices run from $1$ to $2$ just so that you'll see what is going on. I'll assume that $g_{\mu \nu} = g_{\nu \mu}$. Then

$$ T(q^1, q^2, \dot{q}^1, \dot{q}^2, t) = \frac{1}{2} \left( g_{11} \dot{q}^1 \dot{q}^1 + g_{12} \dot{q}^1 \dot{q}^2 + g_{21} \dot{q}^2 \dot{q}^1 + g_{22} \dot{q}^2 \dot{q}^2 \right) + g_{01} \dot{q}^1 + g_{02} \dot{q}^2 + g_{00} = \frac{1}{2} \left(g_{11} \dot{q}^1 \dot{q}^1 + g_{22} \dot{q}^2 \dot{q}^2 \right) + g_{12} \dot{q}^1 \dot{q}^2 + g_{01} \dot{q}^1 + g_{02} \dot{q}^2 + g_{00}  $$

and so, for example,

$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}^1} = g_{11} \dot{q}^1 + g_{12} \dot{q}^2 + g_{01}. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot now it is a bit clearer, there is a way to show the equality keeping the indexes $\lambda$ $\nu$ $\mu$.Excuse the banality of the question but I'm a beginner with indicial notation used in formulas.